# react-dates how to load moment.js async in next.js

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, next.js, momentjs, react-dates

I am using react-dates in my next.js project. Right now I am working on localisation. As I am very keen on having a good performance I don't want to import moment.js synchronous as it is very heavy according to bundlephobia and my own experience (https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=moment@2.29.1).
I want to load moment asynchronous (dynamic import in next.js).

This code works synchronous (normal import statement) in the render function but of course it doesn't work if I load moment dynamic.

```html
import moment from 'moment'; 

...

render () {
...
moment.updateLocale('en', {
  week: {
    dow: 1,
  },
})
...
}
```

So how can I load moment dynamically and update the locale?
Is there a way?

Thank you!

Comment: How have you tried to import `moment` dynamically? Also, keep in mind that Moment.js is a legacy project, and if you're worried about bundle size you should consider moving to a more lightweight alternative like [`date-fns`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns) or [`day.js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dayjs)

Comment: react-dates itself is nice because it also brings the UI with it.
I did load it dynamic like this. 


`import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const Moment = dynamic(() => import("moment"), {
  ... do sth ... if needed ...
});`


The thing is that I need to put the updateLocal function in the render function otherwise moment is not yet defined.